# Django, get list of an attribute for multiple attributes

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

```
id_list = Foo.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
name_list = Foo.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Can I get the two list conveniently, efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by efficiently you mean in a single query, then you can get both attributes in one call and use `zip` to decompose them into separate lists:

```
values = Foo.objects.values_list('id', 'name')
id_list, name_list = zip(*values)
```